# Count row for particular value in DB

Tags: sql

I am using netbeans and making project.
I want for help to count number of rows for Male OR Female from my database.

then I want to display it in JtextField

```
    int count=0;
  String fclass=cmb_PGender.getSelectedItem().toString();
 //  String fclass=txt_PAge.getText();
     String sql="Select * from Patient ";
try {
     ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
      rs=ps.executeQuery();    
      while(rs.next()){
        if(fclass.equals("Male")){
         count++;
       //   txt_count.setText(count);

        }
   }

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Number Of registered patients is "+count+" ");

 } catch (Exception e) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());  
 }
```

Comment: `Select gender,count(*) from Patient group by  gender` could be the classic answer.. but fr learning.. you try to find it via java?

Comment: Can you add the schema to the question? This would be easier to do in just sql.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic here looks pretty messed up:

```
if(fclass.equals("Male")){
    count++;
    //   txt_count.setText(count);
}
```

Essentially if they've selected "Male" it will add one to the count, regardless of whether the current record in the ResultSet is actually a male. You'd be better off executing an SQL query that returns the count of records for that gender, something like this:

```
String fclass=cmb_PGender.getSelectedItem().toString();
String sql="SELECT COUNT(1) AS genderCount FROM Patient WHERE Gender = ?";
int count = 0;

try {
    ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, fClass);
    rs=ps.executeQuery();    

    rs.next();
    count = rs.getInt(1);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "Number Of registered patients is "+count+" ");
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());  
}
```

That assumes you have a column called `Gender` that contains the string "Male" or "Female".

Comment: That works fine.. Thank you all.. Guys,, How to set integer Value into JtextField.. It gives me error.                                        
    rs.next();
    count = rs.getInt(1);
    txt_count_age.setText(count);